# save xml file to different directory

Tags: php, xml

I am looking to save an xml file to a different directory from the root using php5. any ideas?

```
//write to the file
$filename = $id . ".xml";
$doc->save($filename);
```

I want to save the file to the `/xml/` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the argument to `$doc->save` to include the path

```
$filename = '/xml/' . $id . ".xml";
$doc->save($filename);
```

Now the thing to bear in mind is that this is a filesystem path, not web URL so its literally going to save in `/xml` not `DOCUMENT_ROOT/xml`.